# Facebook Graph Limit

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to develop a software with my friend that can scrape Facebook IDs from certain profiles and then check them using the Facebook graph to classify them according to gender. I would like to know what is the limit for checking because I am getting a message that I have reached the limit. Would it be helpful to use proxies that can rotate and move to another when they reach the limit? Also what do you reckon the proxy timeout should be for good and fast results?

Comment: scraping is not allowed: https://www.facebook.com/apps/site_scraping_tos_terms.php

Answer (score 6):

Facebook indeed has a [rate limiting](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/api-rate-limiting) on the Graph API. In general, it comes does to about 600 calls per 600 seconds, per Access Token. You should try to make as many calls as possible with User Access tokens, and others with your App Access token.

Comment: I am a bit confused now since I am not really experienced in that but as far as I know access tokens is used when you have an application right? Because what I am using is not an application, basically I collect links from profiles and check them on graph.facebook.com/username

Comment: In that case, you can still be blocked. In your case the IP address is being flagged as scraping and is throttled.

Comment: But if I am using proxies they will just block the proxy so my app can move to another proxy and continue scraping and checking on graph?

Comment: It seems that at the scale you apparently are intended to scrape information, you are acting against the policy: https://www.facebook.com/apps/site_scraping_tos_terms.php. I advise you to not do this.

Comment: yup, it´s definitely not allowed if you are not even using an app

Comment: I know but I want to know if proxies will do the job because I am not using a Facebook app.

Comment: Read: -it is not allowed-. Please do not ask for things that are not allowed, here on Stackoverflow.

Comment: you KNOW it´s not allowed, but you still want to know how to do it? shame on you. not allowed means: don´t do it. period.

Comment: btw, the answer is correct, but there is no static limit - it depends on many factors and facebook will not thell them so people can´t try to circumvent them.

Comment: Okay, I am sorry did not know that. Anyway I am working on another app for proxy scanning but I want to know if lower proxy timeout means a better proxy? Thank you!

Comment: what exactly are you working on? what do you mean with proxy scanning? you are not allowed to circumvent the api limits, if that´s still what you want to do.

Comment: It is for another app but I kinda misunderstand what proxy timeout is, is it speed of proxy or what? Thank you.

Comment: i am not sure what the relation to the topic of this thread is.